# TensorFlow failed to pip-install on RedHat 6

Tags: python, installation, redhat, tensorflow

I have a RedHat 6 machine with python installed using `miniconda`, so

```
]]] which python
/export/home/my-home-dir-etc-etc-etc/miniconda/bin/python
]]] which pip
/export/home/my-home-dir-etc-etc-etc/miniconda/bin/pip
```

and

```
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.10.1'
```

When I ran

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I got lots of log messages including compile/build errors. I am not dumping the whole log here, just the pieces that I think are crucial, but can add more if needed:

```
 blas_info:
  C compiler: cc

 creating /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp
 creating /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg
 compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/export/home/my-home-dir-etc-etc-etc/miniconda/include -c'
 cc: /tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.c
 cc /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o -L/usr/lib64 -lcblas -o /tmp/tmp72IZmg/a.out
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 cc /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o -L/usr/lib64 -lblas -o /tmp/tmp72IZmg/a.out
 /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o: In function `main':
 source.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o: In function `main':
 source.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/setup.py", line 263, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/setup.py", line 255, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/setup.py", line 156, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('numpy')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "numpy/setup.py", line 17, in configuration
          config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
          caller_level = 2)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
          caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
          config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "numpy/linalg/setup.py", line 26, in configuration
          lapack_info = get_info('lapack_opt', 0) # and {}
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 372, in get_info
          return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 562, in get_info
          self.calc_info()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1571, in calc_info
          blas_info = get_info('blas')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 372, in get_info
          return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 562, in get_info
          self.calc_info()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1690, in calc_info
          lib = self.has_cblas(info)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8ABmqU/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1733, in has_cblas
          extra_postargs=info.get('extra_link_args', []))
      File "/export/home/my-home-dir-etc-etc-etc/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 700, in link_executable
          debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, None, target_lang)
      File "/export/home/my-home-dir-etc-etc-etc/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 200, in link
          raise LinkError, msg

 distutils.errors.LinkError: Command "cc /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o -L/usr/lib64 -lblas -o /tmp/tmp72IZmg/a.out" failed with exit status 1
```

How do I fix this? Thx!

Comment: Did you try running `pip` with super user privileges?

Comment: @Quirk OK, reran it with `sudo` and now only have one error message: `tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` I searched for a solution to this one but the only thing I found so far is a suggestion that I am trying to install a wheel for a 64-bit machine on a 32-bit one. But I am pretty sure I have a 64-bit system, so not sure what's going on. I am wondering if this is because I have RedHat 6 and not RedHat 7 or Ubuntu

Comment: pip uses the filename to check for compatibility. Maybe check uname -a to see what your linux thinks it is?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like You are missing the cblas libraries:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
...
 distutils.errors.LinkError: Command "cc /tmp/tmp72IZmg/tmp/tmp72IZmg/source.o -L/usr/lib64 -lblas -o /tmp/tmp72IZmg/a.out" failed with exit status 1
```

try running `yum install blas blas-devel`

Comment: As Quirk suggested above, I reran with `sudo` but now get a different error. Not sure if installing blas would really help here.

Comment: That previous error does not even start the compilation process because is a system level permission error. Follow my advice and install the blas library   .